# How do I develop a listed paid app for BigCommerce?

Tags: content-management-system, bigcommerce

I want to develop a paid app to be used in BigCommerce and listed in their marketplace. Am I obligated to funnel payments for this app through BigCommerce or can the license payment be done outside of BigCommerce?

Developing the app will obviously have its technical challenges but for now I'm trying to understand whether the merchant can leave the app admin page in BigCommerce to conduct any enrollment steps outside of the CMS. Steps which are obligated as part of the usage of the app.

Answer (score 1):

These are the requirements for BigCommerce Marketplace Apps! I hope this is helpful: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/apps/guide/requirements